# Getting "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED" error

Tags: authentication, docusignapi

While configuring API in Unqork(No-Code platform) getting error "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED" while try to fetch Signed Document.
I have used this API Endpoint - {{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/documents/0

And also getting file in UTF-8 format. But when trying to convert it into PDF than getting blank document.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

#### Unqork

From google searching, it looks like this page may be of help: https://academy.unqork.com/advanced-api-authentication

In general, you need to get unqork to use OAuth with a DocuSign oauth service provider (account-d.docusign.com) to obtain an access token. Then use that access token in unqork's API calls to DocuSign.

Contact unqork's customer service group for more help.

#### General information on the problem

[PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED more information](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/DocuSign-Developer-FAQs-eSignature-API#Partner_Authentication-Failed-Error) error message

Are you using legacy authentication or OAuth authentication? Only OAuth is supported for new integrations.

You must obtain an access token to make API calls. You can obtain an access token via OAuth.

See [the docs](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/). Or a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r0IY6TUrL3Q).

If you want more help, ask a new question and provide more information on exactly what you have tried and what is or is not working.